# Manipulate a multi-dimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following Array in hand. I have to iterate the following array in order that it will create another array with an output of 0th index of every sub-array on the 0th index of new array and so on.

**Current Array**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
            )

    )
```

**Desired Output**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 3
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PHP versions >= 5.5.0 you have the [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$newArray = array_column(
    $oldArray,
    0
);
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$column = 0;
$newArray = array_map(
    function ($value) use ($column) {
        return $value[$column];
    },
    $oldArray
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark you got me out of a big mess. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That's not allot of info to work with...so, something like:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($topArray as $idxTop => $valTop){
  if(is_array($valTop)){($newArray[] = $valTop[0];}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = [
    0 => [1, 2, 3],
    1 => [1, 2, 3],
    2 => [1, 2, 3]
];

$output = [
    array_column($input, 0),
    array_column($input, 1),
    array_column($input, 2)
];

print_r($output);

// Output:
// 
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 1
//             [1] => 1
//             [2] => 1
//         )

//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 2
//             [1] => 2
//             [2] => 2
//         )

//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 3
//             [1] => 3
//             [2] => 3
//         )

// )
```